# Format of hiddev bytes?

Tags: usb, devices, hid

I have a gamma spectrometer that connects as a USB HID.  When it is inserted `dmesg` helpfully informs me that two device files were made for it, `hiddev0` and `hidraw2` (obviously, the numbering isn't important.)

Based on the documentation and a visual inspection of the bytes, I want to be reading from `hidraw2`.  But I am curious what sort of data is coming through `hiddev0`, because I was stuck trying to figure it out for a while before I noticed `hidraw2` existed.

Here is some example data from `hiddev0`.

```
00000000  01 00 00 ff 0d 00 00 00  01 00 00 ff 81 00 00 00  |................|
00000010  01 00 00 ff 0b 00 00 00  01 00 00 ff 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  01 00 00 ff 0e 00 00 00  01 00 00 ff c1 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  01 00 00 ff 08 00 00 00  01 00 00 ff 01 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  01 00 00 ff 08 00 00 00  01 00 00 ff 41 00 00 00  |............A...|
00000050  01 00 00 ff 0b 00 00 00  01 00 00 ff 31 00 00 00  |............1...|
00000060  01 00 00 ff 07 00 00 00  01 00 00 ff b1 00 00 00  |................|
00000070  01 00 00 ff 09 00 00 00  01 00 00 ff 01 00 00 00  |................|
00000080  01 00 00 ff 08 00 00 00  01 00 00 ff b1 00 00 00  |................|
00000090  01 00 00 ff 08 00 00 00  01 00 00 ff 51 00 00 00  |............Q...|
000000a0  01 00 00 ff 1d 00 00 00  01 00 00 ff 51 00 00 00  |............Q...|
000000b0  01 00 00 ff 0a 00 00 00  01 00 00 ff f1 00 00 00  |................|
000000c0  01 00 00 ff 08 00 00 00  01 00 00 ff 51 00 00 00  |............Q...|
000000d0  01 00 00 ff 34 00 00 00  01 00 00 ff 91 00 00 00  |....4...........|
```

As requested, here is the line from `dmesg`.

`[411407.529580] hid-generic 0003:04D8:0023.0003: hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.01 Device [Kromek SIGMA50] on usb-0000:00:1a.1-2/input0`

Comment: Please edit your question with the exact lines from `dmesg`, because these could give a hint what kind of HID translation the kernel uses. Guess: The it's some kind of generic translation of the raw values using the HID descriptor, so decoding the HID descriptor might tell you something.

Comment: http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial answer:

The driver is `hid-generic`, so the next step is to look at the HID descriptor. As root, do

```
mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug
```

And then look at the contents of `/sys/kernel/debug/hid/<dev>/rdesc`, where `<dev>` identifies your device.

The HID descriptor describes the format of what you can read from and write to the `hidraw` descriptor (maybe also important for you). These are processed by the kernel HID parser, and then sent to the `hiddev` descriptor. At least for input devices, the above file also has information about what the kernel parser does with the information, but I'm not sure what happens for `hid-generic`.

Comparing what you see on `hidraw` and `hiddev` should allow some pretty good guesses about what the kernel parser does, and in doubt one can read the source.

You can find more information in `Documentation/hid/hidraw.txt` and `/Documentation/hid/hiddev.txt` in the kernel sources.

The ["hidpage"](http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/) from the comments has the HID standards, if you want to read those.

Comment: This is enough to point me in the right direction.  Thanks!